# CSS Div, classes and spans

Tags: css

Can some one please expalin to me these two selectors, I cant get my head around it

```
div.card div

div.card div span
```

Comment: What two selectors you are presenting only one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Whitespace in a selector means "descendant of", so `div.card div` means "A div that is a descendant (e.g., child, grandchild, great-grandchild) of a div with a class of `card`". `div.card div span` means "a span that is a descendant of a div that is a descendant of a div with class `card`."

Given the HTML:

```
<div id="d1" class="foo">
  <div id="d2" class="card">
    <span id="s1"></span>
    <div id="d3" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="d4" class="bar">
      <div id="d5"><span id="s2"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The selector `div.card div` would match the divs with IDs `d3`, `d4`, and `d5`. Note that it doesn't match the `card` div (id `d2`) itself.

The selector `div.card div span` would match the span with id `s2`, but NOT `s1`. The `s1` span does not descend from a div that is a child of `div.card`, so it wouldn't match.

Comment: So the selector `div.card div, span` would match the S1?

Comment: Yes, because a comma separates multiple selectors, that string would match *both* the divs matched by `div.card div` AND the spans `s1` and `s2`

Answer (score 2):

div.card div - all div's inside div with class `card`

div.card div span - all span's inside div's inside div with class `card`

Answer (score 0):

Read from the right to the left: the first one is "div inside (div with class 'card')". The second one is "span inside div inside (div with class 'card')".

Answer (score 0):

In HTML something like this:

div.card div

```
<div class="card">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

div.card div span

```
<div class="card">
   <div>
      <span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```